# Adding a newline to textbox in a loop structure

Tags: c#, loops, textbox

I'm working on my assignment and I've hit a roadblock, been trying to figure out where I'm going wrong in this code. I've searched a fair bit but couldn't find a solution. This is my code.

```
float Counter = 5.0f;
while (Counter < 24.0f)
{
    string Output = "";
    Output += Counter;
    txtAvgTemp.Text = Output.ToString();
    Counter += 1.5f;
    txtAvgTemp.Text.Split('\n');
}
```

my output data just shows 23, it goes through the loop and replaces all the previous string, I would like it too start from 5, print, then add 1.5, print. any help would be appreciated thank you.

Thanks for all the reponses it worked!!
I have to add a calculation as part of the counter.
but its giving me a unhandled error, where im trying to float.parse(volume) not sure why here is the code.

`string AvgTempOutput = "";
        string volume;
        float Counter = 5.0f;
        float heatingCost;

```
    while (Counter < 24.0f)
    {
        AvgTempOutput += Counter;
        txtAvgTemp.Text += Counter.ToString() + "\r\n";

        volume = txtVolume.Text;
        heatingCost = (25.0f - Counter) * float.Parse(volume);
        txtTableDollars.Text = heatingCost.ToString() + "r\n";

        Counter += 1.5f;


    }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing your text on each loop instead of adding new line to it as your are mentioning. Change the code like this

```
float Counter = 5.0f;
string Output = "";
while (Counter < 24.0f)
{
    Output += Counter;
    txtAvgTemp.Text += "\r\n" + Output.ToString(); //Appending the text
    Counter += 1.5f;
}
```

Comment: I'd also consider replacing `"\r\n"` with `Environment.NewLine` as it is more readable and also better in possible future usages as c# and .net in general opens up for other platforms than just windows

Comment: I need to add a calculation to this counter and I'm having trouble parsing a textbox into a float to get the calculation going.

Do I need to ask another question? I'm having trouble posting it here

Answer (score 0):

you should declare out while your variable ,like this :

```
string Output = "";
while (Counter < 24.0f)
{

    Output += Counter;
    txtAvgTemp.Text = Output.ToString();
    Counter += 1.5f;
    txtAvgTemp.Text.Split('\n');
}
```

in your code , each time Output clear when start new loop .
its better replace `String` with `StringBuilder` Like this :

```
StringBuilder Output=new StringBuilder("");
```